# Can we use pip downloaded files after an install error?

Tags: python, ruby, rubygems, pip

This is a newbee question. I forgot to add sudo before my pip install, and got the permission denied message after a whole while. Is there a method by which I can make use of the downloaded files when I invoke the pip command with sudo subsequently, so that I can save bandwidth.
Ditto with gem install.
Thanks.

Comment: Why is this both Ruby and Python in the same question?

Comment: @tadman Please see the last line of my post.

Comment: You can't just "ditto" and expect an answer. Ask two questions.

Comment: While reading <http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/shipping/packaging/> I came across the topic Personal PyPI. I can just download the tar.gz(s) and run the python SimpleHTTPServer and pip install through that. Of course we have to use `sudo`. Someone might like this.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do what you're asking, at least not easily and securely.

To do what you want would involve changing the user ownership of parts of your system, which would be bad for a lot of reasons. Or, you'd have to change the group or add yourself to the group, which would be bad for the same reasons as the first. In both cases, the odds of you damaging your system beyond repair goes way up.

We have `sudo` for a reason; It's to keep us from running as the system administrator all the time and shooting ourselves in the foot. Invoking a command using `sudo` gives us a chance to pause and think whether we want to do that. It also adds a thin layer of sanity-checking code that looks to see if that is a safe command to issue, which you can tweak to allow/disallow particular actions.

If you choose to go the last route, how to do that is off-topic for Stack Overflow and should be asked on http://superuser.com instead.